# Weird input error when taking Sdin(or non-interactive) input | Java

Tags: java, debugging, input, runtime-error, stdin

This is my simple Java code to take input and print output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    //weird input problem
    class Student{
        private int rollno;
        private String name;
        public void getRollNo(){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter name and roll no");
            name=sc.next();
            rollno=sc.nextInt();
        }
        public void putRollNo(){
            System.out.println("Name="+name);
            System.out.println("Regno="+rollno);
        }
    }
    class Marks extends Student{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        protected int Mark1,Mark2,Mark3;
        public void getMarks(){
            System.out.println("Enter 3 Marks");
            Mark1=sc.nextInt();
            Mark2=sc.nextInt();
            Mark3=sc.nextInt();
        }
        public void putMarks(){
            System.out.println("Mark1="+Mark1);
            System.out.println("Mark2="+Mark2);
            System.out.println("Mark3="+Mark3);
        }
    }
    class Result extends Marks{
        void computeDisplay(){
            float total = Mark1 + Mark2 + Mark3;
            System.out.println("Total="+ total);
        }
    }
    public class MyClass{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Result r = new Result();
            r.getRollNo();
            r.getMarks();
            r.putRollNo();
            r.putMarks();
            r.computeDisplay();
        }
    }
```

So it works perfectly when the input is given line by line(interactive console input) here's what console of my IDE shows

```
Enter name and roll no
John
1234
Enter 3 Marks
11
22
33
Name=John
Regno=1234
Mark1=11
Mark2=22
Mark3=33
Total=66.0
```

The real problem is when I give the input as text.
I am giving this as input-

```
John
1234
11
22
33
```

It looks like the program is just ignoring some input(In this case, the "Marks") so I had to input the marks again. Console output-

```
Enter name and roll no
John
1234
11
22
33Enter 3 Marks
1
2
3
Name=John
Regno=1234
Mark1=1
Mark2=2
Mark3=3
Total=6.0
```

And when I give the input in the [jdoodle compiler](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler) with "Interactive Mode" set to "OFF", it just returns this error-

```
Enter name and roll no
Enter 3 Marks

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:858)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1497)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2161)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2115)
at Marks.getMarks(MyClass.java:22)
at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:42)

Command exited with non-zero status 1
```

I have no clue. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Java `Scanner` waits for you until input is sent to console and Carriage Return is hit. Your program is working as expected.

However, you want to take all inputs in a sequential manner, try this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while(input.hasNext()) {  
     roll = input.nextInt();
     marks = input.nextInt();
     ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not taking input from a file, i'm just giving my whole input as text or all input at once, sorry i don't know what exactly it is called

Comment: Ok then reformat your code to accept the whole sequence at once. Write a method called `getResult()`, which will take comma separated Roll, Marks touples, which you can then `split(",")`. It's against the SO rule to give you the full code.

Comment: Sorry, the inputs are not in one line, its like when you give the whole input in non-interactive text field of an online compiler(Stdin input is it?) like in the image- [link](https://imgur.com/a/iKsTM)

Comment: Understood, please check my updated answer. Again, I can't provide you exact implementation. Try using these loops in `getRoll()` and `getMarks()`

Comment: I used your loop in the getMarks() method, now the error is gone, but the values now set in all 3 Marks are 0